# Ajax not working in cordova after build apk

Tags: php, android, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I tried to make an application to cordova and connect with php server that has been my hosting. when I run in the browser with localhost her work , but after I build apk and connected host ajax not want to work , what no additional configuration ??

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //insert data
    $("#insert").click(function(){
        var qrcode=$("#qrcode").val();
        var judul=$("#judul").val();
        var pengarang=$("#pengarang").val();
        var jilid=$("#jilid").val();
        var tahun=$("#tahun").val();
        var dataString="qrcode="+qrcode+"&judul="+judul+"&pengarang="+pengarang+"&jilid="+jilid+"&tahun="+tahun+"&insert=";
        if($.trim(qrcode).length>0 & $.trim(judul).length>0 & $.trim(pengarang).length>0)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                //url: "http://phonegappro.esy.es/test/insert.php",
                url:"http://bbicpretest.esy.es/insert.php",
                data: dataString,
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(){ $("#insert").val('Connecting...');},
                success: function(data){
                    if(data=="ok")
                    {
                        alert("inserted");
                        $("#qrcode").val('');
                        $("#judul").val('');
                        $("#pengarang").val('');
                        $('#jilid').prop('selectedIndex',0);
                        $("#tahun").val('');
                        $("#insert").val('Insert');
                    }
                    else if(data=="error")
                    {
                        alert("error");
                         $("#insert").val('Insert');
                    }
                }
            });
        }return false;
    });
```

Comment: which version of Cordova are you using? Have you added Cordova whitelist plugin and corresponding entries in config.xml?

Comment: thanks @Gandhi , I use the CLI version 6.1.1 cordoav . yes when I added platforms cordova android-plugin-whitelist will be automatically saved .

Comment: Could you please post your config.xml?

Comment: this [config.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2XIOW0-UhurN05nbFl5ZW04eDA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you also post your index.html, specificially the `<head>` so we can see what value you are using for the Content Security Policy meta tag.

Comment: @SimonPrickett, nice its solve after I added the meta tag Content Security Policy, and there are also some scripts that must be corrected in index.html and finally ajax running.